# Services/Processes running Per RDS Session

Tags: windows-server-2008, rds

I have a box running Server 2008 R2 with RDS. We currently have 45 RDS sessions running on this system and most are running identical applications.

Now we are wanting to add 30 more systems that will be using RDS but will be running different programs.

My Question is: 
What is the best way to keep services related to these programs from starting on all other RDS sessions when they start? I don't want a program loading into the taskbar or running a process in the background on every terminal if it will only be used on 4 or 5 terminals.

Comment: What makes you think that programs pinned to the taskbar are actually running on every session?

Comment: @ChrisS When I open task manager and show processes from all users, the process for this program is running under each username.

Comment: If that's the case then something else is starting the program, it's not just pinned to the task bar. Mitch has some good info below regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a program is starting on login, it has to be started by some configurable means.  Use [`autoruns`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) or similar to identify the start mechanism.

Once identified, remove any global settings, and use group policy to have the auto-start only apply to those users with access to the program.

Example:

Delete the HKLM autostart for all users

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
SomeAutoStart=C:\Program Files\foo\bar.exe
```

And replace it with a group policy which creates it in

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
SomeAutoStart=C:\Program Files\foo\bar.exe
```

**Note:** I lied a little when I said "has to be [...] configurable".  There is at least one way which does not have configuration.  It is a favorite of printer drivers which uses a process running with the [`SeTcbPrivilege`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221957(v=ws.10).aspx) to start a process in a users session.  But usually my statement holds true.